# How to get a Gradle task to execute Spring Boot test cases through a Groovy script?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

The background to this is as follows.

1. I need to run some tests (let's call it TestClass) that are annotated as `@SpringBootTest` and are JUnit tests
2. The TestClass is invoked by a runner in TestScript.groovy (which is a Groovy script)
3. This TestScript collates all the tests results

In order to do this, I created the following build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'org.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

sourceSets {
  test {
    groovy {
    srcDirs = 'src/test'
    }
  }
}

test {
  exclude 'com/domain/test/**' // This is to avoid this task running any of the tests without TestScript.groovy
}

task runtest(type: JavaExec) {
  dependsOn test // because test task builds from source
  
  args '-env', 'test' // program arguments
  main 'com.domain.test.TestScript'
  jvmArgs ['spring.profiles.active=test']
  classpath configuration.compile, configurations.runtime, sourceSets.test.output, sourceSets.main.output, configurations.compileClasspath, configurations.runtimeClasspath
}
```

The project file structure is as follows:

```
project-root
  src
    main
      java
        com
          domain
            SomeClass.java // These are needed for the JUnit tests
    test
      java
        com
          domain
            test
              TestScript.groovy
              TestClass.java
```

The main issue is that TestScript.groovy when calling TestClass.java is ignoring SpringBootTest. Instead it just runs the test method without Spring Boot, and of course no dependency injection occurs so the test fails with null pointer exceptions.

So to execute this, at the command line I type:

`$ ./gradlew clean runtest`

Now, I know you should be able to do this, because IntelliJ will run this setup just fine. However, I'm unable to decipher what they really did (even after studying the incredibly long command they run on the command line).

Anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work as I'm 3-4 days out of solutions?

Comment: *TestClass is invoked by a runner in TestScript.groovy* Why are you doing this instead of using the bog-standard test infrastructure?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- 
I'm using someone else library and that is how they did it. I don't have a choice in the decision around that. Basiaclly what that TestScript does is listen in on the unit tests and exports the test results elsewhere. So what it really does is 1. read in all tests 2. execute the tests while listening in on test results 3. collect all results 4. export it elsewhere.

Comment: I guess it depends on what `TestScript` actually does. But just looking at the Gradle build file, I would expect the classpath to be exactly `sourceSets.main.output, sourceSets.test.output, configurations.testRuntimeClasspath`. Otherwise you have duplicates, possible unnecessary dependencies and are missing the test dependencies. But in any case, if at all possible, try and convince whoever is responsible for this build that it should be standardized - it looks a bit like a quick and dirty migration from perhaps an old Ant script, and it does not support things like proper up-to-date checking.

Comment: Regarding my comment above, you can even simplify the classpath further to only be `sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath`. This contains both dependencies, resources and compiled classes from both the main and the test source sets.

Comment: @BjørnVester Thank you for the suggestion. I will update it. Unfortunately, at this time, I'm stuck with this, but hopefully it can be fixed later as a tech debt. The main issue now is that it doesn't seem to start Spring Boot to run the test so the auto-injection from Spring doesn't happen and we get a null pointer exception. I'm not sure what we need to do to get Spring Boot running?